# Not getting JSON POST values from volley stringRequest

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

AnyBody, please solve my issue. I am unable to get any POST values from volley StringRequest.What is the Problem in my code

Here is my Android Code

```
     StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Log.d("response",response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(PostRequestTest.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
    {
        //getaParams function is used to send the values to the server
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_name","uname");
            Log.d("parameters09876", params.toString());
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(params);
            Log.d("jsonRequest",jsonObject.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            Config.MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

And in my PHP Code, i simply Print the POST value

```
<?php echo $_POST['user_name']; ?>
```

Here is my CustomVolleyRequest

```
public class CustomVolleyRequest  {
private static CustomVolleyRequest customVolleyRequest;
private static Context context;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private CustomVolleyRequest(Context context) {
    this.context = context  ;
    this.requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);
                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    return cache.get(url);
                }
                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            });
}
public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequest getInstance(Context context) {
    if (customVolleyRequest == null) {
        customVolleyRequest = new CustomVolleyRequest(context);
    }
    return customVolleyRequest;
}
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (requestQueue == null) {
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        requestQueue.start();
    }
    return requestQueue;
}
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req)
{
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
public ImageLoader getImageLoader()
{
    return imageLoader;
}
```

}

Comment: `Log.d("response",response);` what is the log? and you are not sending/receiving json

Comment: your code from android side looks fine can you show me the php code

Comment: Are you getting the response? Please include it

Comment: I am getting the POST value as my response. Simply Want to show POST value.but the POST value is not showing @LManoj

Comment: In PHP I am just printing the POSTvalue. I already show my PHP code in my question @adam

Comment: $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");    var_dump($rawData) ; check what you getting from this.

Comment: using this you can get parameters are passing.

Answer (score 1):

I give one suggestion to you. use `JsonObjectRequest` instead of using `StringRequest`.

`StringRequest`:  Specify a URL and receive a raw string in response.

`JsonObjectRequest` and `JsonArrayRequest` (both subclasses of JsonRequest). Specify a URL and get a JSON object or array (respectively) in response.

```
TextView mTxtDisplay;
ImageView mImageView;
mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

[See this docs](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Comment: Not Working with JsonObjectRequest :(

Comment: $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input"); var_dump($rawData) ; did you check this one in your server side?

Comment: did you give permission to internet connection . like <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Previously it was working but after updating my android studio this problems occur

Comment: In your code add this line `RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);` and remove  `CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);`

Comment: or share the `CustomVolleyRequest`

Comment: Same response string(0) ""

Comment: CustomVolleyRequest added in Question

Comment: maybe your server file didn't call. pls check with the POSTMAN. in postman give the values as parameter and give url and check the result is fine or not.

Comment: POSTMAN also not returning any value..i think the problem is in my server but what? currently i am converting my http to https.

Comment: Server File is called but it does not get any POST value

Comment: It's not getting POST value. May be your file didn't call. In your PHP file give some echo statement and call it. Remove post value. Check your File calling or not.

Comment: Now file is calling and POST value is also going with POSTMAN

Comment: is there any problem of https.

Comment: Do 1 thing. Try to call php file in Android .don't get the POST value. Just call the php file.

Comment: yes i also do that.. i am getting value that i simply echo but not getting POST variable value

Comment: Finally...Done brother..thanks a lot for your precious time.... the root cause was there was my file was in http and while the domain had been converted into https so issue was the mismatching.After made change it is working fine:)